# How do I set LogicalScreenDescriptor and ImageDescriptor gif metadata

Tags: image, image-processing, javafx, gif

I want to create a GIF with a Logical Screen Descriptor larger than any image that I have in my gif image sequence.  Each image in the gif will have its top and left offset modified. Here's the code I have that looks like it ought to work, but it doesn't

```
void test() throws IOException {

    Image image1 = textToImage ("m",12.0 );
    Image image2 = textToImage("n", 24.0);

    Image[] images = {image2, image1};

    String[] imageTopOffset = {"6", "30"};
    String[] imageLeftOffset = {"6", "36"};

    ImageWriter iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif").next();
    ImageWriteParam params = iw.getDefaultWriteParam();
    int type = ((BufferedImage)getRenderedImage(image1)).getType();
    ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(type);

    IIOMetadata metadata = iw.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier, params);
    IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode)metadata.getAsTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());

    IIOMetadataNode lsdNode = getNode(root, "LogicalScreenDescriptor");
    lsdNode.setAttribute("logicalScreenHeight", "100");
    lsdNode.setAttribute("logicalScreenWidth", "75");

    IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(root, "GraphicControlExtension");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorFlag", "FALSE");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("delayTime", "100");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorIndex", "0");

    IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(root, "CommentExtensions");
    commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by: http://example.com");

    IIOMetadataNode appExtensionsNode = getNode(root, "ApplicationExtensions");
    IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
    child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
    child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
    boolean loop = true;
    int loopContinuously = loop ? 0 : 1;
    child.setUserObject(new byte[]{ 0x1, (byte) (loopContinuously & 0xFF), (byte) ((loopContinuously >> 8) & 0xFF)});
    appExtensionsNode.appendChild(child);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    iw.setOutput(ios);
    iw.prepareWriteSequence(metadata);
    int i = 0;
    for (Image image : images) {
        graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(root, "GraphicControlExtension");
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("delayTime", "50");
        IIOMetadataNode imageDescriptorNode = getNode(root, "ImageDescriptor");
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageLeftPosition", imageLeftOffset[i]);
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageTopPosition", imageTopOffset[i]);
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageWidth", String.valueOf(image.getWidth()));
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageHeight", String.valueOf(image.getHeight()));
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("interlaceFlag", "FALSE");

        IIOImage ii = new IIOImage(getRenderedImage(image), null, metadata);
        iw.writeToSequence(ii, params);
        i++;
    }
    iw.endWriteSequence();
    ios.close();

    byte[] gifContent = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    File outputFile = new File("test.gif");
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        outputStream.write(gifContent);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}


private WritableImage textToImage(String text, Double size) {

    Text t = new Text();
    t.setFont(getFont("Calibi",
            "NORMAL",
            "REGULAR",
            size));
    t.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    t.setText(text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(t));
    return t.snapshot(null, null);
}

IIOMetadataNode getNode(IIOMetadataNode rootNode, String name) {
    NodeList childNodes  = rootNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if (childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().equals(name) ) {
            return (IIOMetadataNode)childNodes.item(i);
        }
    }
    // no child node with the given name found, create one!
    IIOMetadataNode metadataNode = new IIOMetadataNode(name);
    rootNode.appendChild(metadataNode);
    return  metadataNode;
}

Font getFont(String fontname, String fontWeight, String fontPosture, double size) {
    FontPosture posture = FontPosture.valueOf(fontPosture);
    FontWeight weight = FontWeight.valueOf(fontWeight);
    Font font = Font.font (fontname, weight, posture, size);
    return font;
}

public RenderedImage getRenderedImage(Image image) {
    return SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
}
```

The gif image it produces is the size of the first image in the sequence even though I set the LogicalScreenDescriptor to a bigger size than the image that gets written out.  The actual size of the gif is the size of the 1st image.  The other problem is that imageTopPosition and imageLeftPosition doesn't get applied.

The two images are of different sizes.  The two images are generated, one image is a 12 point image of the letter m, and the other image is a 24 point image of the letter n.

So how do I make a larger logical screen descriptor and how do I change the image descriptor offsets.  Although the above code looks like it should work, it doesn't.  Most examples I've found assume that all images in a gif are the same size and that the display of subsequent images in the gif completely replace the previous image.

Comment: When debugging, I looked at iw.canReplaceStreamMetadata() and I get the value of false.  That seems to explain why setting the LogicalScreenDiscriptor parmeters has no effect.  As a matter of fact, when I dump the gif file I produced, I was able to also not find the comment that I had added. So that too is explained by the fact that "canReplaceStreamMetadata" is false. What I don't understand is what I have to change or do so I can replace streamMetadata. Do I need a different GIF ImageWriter?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the coding changes I made that solved the problem for the gif not displaying properly:

```
 void test() throws IOException {

    Image image1 = textToImage ("m",12.0 );
    Image image2 = textToImage("n", 24.0);

    Image[] images = {image2, image1};

    String[] imageTopOffset = {"6", "30"};
    String[] imageLeftOffset = {"6", "36"};

    ImageWriter iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/gif").next();
    ImageWriteParam params = iw.getDefaultWriteParam();
    int type = ((BufferedImage)getRenderedImage(image1)).getType();
    ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(type);

    IIOMetadata imageMetadata = iw.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier, params);
    IIOMetadata streamMetadata = iw.getDefaultStreamMetadata(params);
    IIOMetadataNode streamRoot = (IIOMetadataNode)streamMetadata.getAsTree(streamMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());
    IIOMetadataNode imageRoot = (IIOMetadataNode)imageMetadata.getAsTree(imageMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    iw.setOutput(ios);

    IIOMetadataNode lsdNode = getNode(streamRoot, "LogicalScreenDescriptor");
    lsdNode.setAttribute("logicalScreenHeight", "100");
    lsdNode.setAttribute("logicalScreenWidth", "75");
/*
 *      The following extension nodes may not be put in the streamMetadata. If you do add them
 *      to the streamMetadata you'll get any error when you prepareWriteSequence
 *
    IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(streamRoot, "GraphicControlExtension");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorFlag", "FALSE");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("delayTime", "100");
    graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("transparentColorIndex", "0");

    IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(streamRoot, "CommentExtensions");
    commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by: http://example.com");

    IIOMetadataNode appExtensionsNode = getNode(streamRoot, "ApplicationExtensions");
    IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
    child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
    child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
    boolean loop = true;
    int loopContinuously = loop ? 0 : 1;
    child.setUserObject(new byte[]{ 0x1, (byte) (loopContinuously & 0xFF), (byte) ((loopContinuously >> 8) & 0xFF)});
    appExtensionsNode.appendChild(child);

 */
    streamMetadata.setFromTree(streamMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(), streamRoot);
    iw.prepareWriteSequence(streamMetadata);
    int i = 0;
    for (Image image : images) {
        IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(imageRoot, "GraphicControlExtension");
        graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("delayTime", "50");
        IIOMetadataNode imageDescriptorNode = getNode(imageRoot, "ImageDescriptor");
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageLeftPosition", imageLeftOffset[i]);
        imageDescriptorNode.setAttribute("imageTopPosition", imageTopOffset[i]);
        imageMetadata.setFromTree(imageMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(),imageRoot);
        IIOImage ii = new IIOImage(getRenderedImage(image), null, imageMetadata);
        iw.writeToSequence(ii, params);
        i++;
    }
    iw.endWriteSequence();
    ios.close();

    byte[] gifContent = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    File outputFile = new File("test.gif");
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        outputStream.write(gifContent);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

The prepareWriteSequence command did not like streamMetadata that contains the extensions graphicControlExtension and ApplicationExtensions.  I figured that out by examining the source code for GifImageWriter.  There's also some problem with the value I provided to the set "imageWidth and "imageHeight". Not sure what the value for those attributes should look like.  I just avoid that problem by not setting those values.

The output is a 75x100 gif with a 12pt letter m offset by 30 from the top and 36 from the left and a 24 point letter n offset 6 from the top and 6 from the left.